# FAB not taking color from theme

Tags: android

I have a FAB in my layout as:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                    android:id="@+id/click_receipt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_margin="08dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_photo" />
```

The theme I use for this `Activity` is:

```
 <!-- Detail Activity-->

<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="searchViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.SearchView</item>
</style>
```

However the colorPrimary / colorPrimaryDark dont seem to take effect on the FAB.

Earlier I was using a universal theme for the app which is:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionBar_bg</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

        <item name="android:background">@color/actionBar_bg</item>
        <item name="background">@color/actionBar_bg</item>

    </style>
```

The results with above were proper, but I dont find much difference in my custom theme for this `Activity`, what do I miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FAB is taking colorAccent - you will have to set this

Comment: Let me check that! Yes that does it :) Thanks mate